# Java HashMultiMap Storing Issue

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, guava

I am using [HashMultiMap](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashMultimap.html) in my code. My HashMultiMap structure is like,

> Key1 -> Value11 -> Value12 -> Value13 ....
>
> Key2 -> Value21 -> Value22 ....

Now, I want if key1 has same values (example: value11 = value12) then keep (or do not store) only one copy of the value (example: keep only value11 or do not store value12). Can anybody help me how to achieve this with an efficient (faster) way.

Comment: What type are `values` in your code? Did you implement `equals()` correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [`HashMultiMap`](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashMultimap.html) Javadoc, you chose the right MultiMap for that purpose:

> The multimap does not store duplicate key-value pairs. Adding a new key-value pair equal to an existing key-value pair has no effect.

Now, you only have to make sure that `equals()` (and `hashCode()`) is implemented correctly on your values. I don't think you should worry about a faster way to do this. The `HashMultiMap` should be implemented pretty efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

If you want this behavior why not use a structure like:

```
Map<Key,Set<Values>> myMap = new HashMap<Key,Set<Values>>();
```

EDIT:

If you want to use the HashMultiMap i would recommend the one bellow

> Implementation of the MultiMap interface that uses a HashMap for the
>   map and HashSets for automatically created sets.
>
> http://people.csail.mit.edu/milch/blog/apidocs/common/HashMultiMap.html

Comment: why cant he use a MultiHashMap? Doesnt it make sure all values for a key are unique?